# DataFrame index is clearly a DateTimeIndex but .plot() can't graph it properly?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I made a very simple two-column excel file with date and random float to test some other stuff. I read_excel() with parse_dates=True on the first column, and verified type(df.index) = .

When I go to .plot(), the x-axis of the graph is a bunch of random years like 2016 then 1987 then 1678...and none of my values show up of course (y-axis is correct though).
What did I miss?

The xlsx:
The column A is formatted as Short-Date in excel; B is just General

```
_____|    A        |     B    |
 0   | 2019-01-01        12.87
 1   | 2019-01-02        15.20
 ..
 90  | 2019-03-31        10.12
```

The code is:

```
fakedf = pd.read_excel('sampledata.xlsx', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, header=None)
fakedf.index.name = 'Date'
fakedf.columns = ['Price']
fakedf.head()
```

From there there is a decent plot but when I do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [np.nan], 'Price': [np.nan]})
df.index = df.Date
del df['Date']

for x in range(len(fakedf)):
    df = df.append(fakedf.iloc[x])
df.plot()
```

It messes up. I had the for loop there because I was trying to test something relating to time.sleep()

Comment: Can  you share your excel file? and code to plot.

Comment: @ScottBoston new to Stack idk how to do that so I edited the original lmao..hope that works